# Remove Safe Area from IOS 13

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios13, navigationbar

How do you make the safe area transparent? It seems to show up on some of my ViewControllers but not on others.  The snap shot is from one using a TabViewController.  I have been able to remove the header but I cannot get the safe area to go away.

[image]

Comment: The safe area is just a layout constraint, it doesn't actually appear on screen. What you're seeing there is probably a navigation bar or status bar. Are you using a navigation controller? I'm not sure how to remove it, but this might help you when searching for answers.

Comment: Thanks! That helped, I was opening the tab with a navigation controller instead of just calling the tabcontoller!